# How to make models from external table data PHP and Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, dom

I am currently trying to pull some data from an external website in order to create models for my website. I am able to get the data from the table that I want, but have not been able to figure out exactly how to manipulate the data to structure my models. For each row in the table, there is certain data that I want to extract. As it currently stands, I am creating a `player` model with all of the player names, but now need to figure out how to attach the data that I want from each row to each player. Here is my code so far:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$html = file_get_contents('https://www.baseball-reference.com/register/team.cgi?id=41270199');
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$table = $dom->getElementByID('team_batting');
$stats = $table->getElementsByTagName("td");

for ($i = 0; $i < $stats->length; $i++) {
// get player name
$attr = $stats->item($i)->getAttribute('data-stat');
if ($attr != 'player') {
    continue;
}
$names[] = $stats->item($i)->textContent;
}

foreach($names as $name) {
    $player = new Player(['name' => $name]);
    echo $player;
    echo '<br>';
}
```

So how would I get certain table data, like `age`, `H`, `HR`, and other things, and appropriately attach this data to the correct player model?

EDIT/UPDATE:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$html = file_get_contents('https://www.baseball-reference.com/register/team.cgi?id=41270199');
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$table = $dom->getElementByID('team_batting');

$rows = $table->getElementsByTagName("tr");

for($i = 0; $i < $rows->length; $i++) {

$stats = $table->getElementsByTagName("td");

for($i = 0; $i < $stats->length; $i++) {

    $name = $stats->item($i)->getAttribute('player');
    $age = $stats->item($i)->getAttribute('age');

    $names[] = $stats->item($i)->textContent;
    $ages[] = $stats->item($i)->textContent;

    dd($ages);
}

}
```

Comment: Before looping through all the `td`s, loop through the `tr`s which represent rows. Then loop through the `td`s of each row and just like you are doing for the player name, check if the data-stat attribute is the one you want and add it to your list of players.

Comment: I think I understand the logic of your comment but am still not sure how to implement something to make it functional. I've tried what you suggested, but even when I `dd($ages)` I get the first players name.

Comment: @solarc okay so actually, I was able to figure out how to get all the attributes I need by using ` $name = $stats->item(0)->textContent;` for each attribute, but is there a way to do this without using array position in case it changes and for more clarity?